# Does the Hamiltonian for a quantized EM field neglect non-radiate field?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, hamiltonian

Suppose positive and negative charges are separated into different objects by friction in some inertial lab frame. Those objects are then moved to opposite directions along the $x$ axis, with an initial velocity big enough to balance the electrostatic attraction, so that they will get zero velocity at infinity.

The charges will be accelerated all the time, so they radiate. But the radiation becomes weaker as the distance increase and the acceleration tends to zero.

I don't see any conceptual difficulties for the classical electromagnetism to describe the total field at any point close to one of the charges, when approaching infinity. For a far away charge, with almost constant velocity $v$, the contribution from radiation is too small, and the energy of the electromagnetic field at a point (x,y,z) not far from that charge and a time $t$, tends to $$\frac{\epsilon_0 E^2+(\frac{1}{\mu_0})B^2}{2}$$ where $$\mathbf E(t,x,y,z) = \frac{kq\gamma}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}((x - vt),y,z)$$
and $$\mathbf B(t,x,y,z) = \frac{kq\gamma}{(\gamma^2 (x - vt)^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}(0,-\beta z,\beta y)$$ Those fields solve all the Maxwell equations for vacuum solution.

But what about QED? According to [this](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/six.pdf) reference, the Hamiltonian of the electromagnetic field (for the Lorentz gauge) is $$H = \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} |\mathbf p|(\sum_1^3 a_p^{i\dagger}a_p^i - a_p^{0\dagger}a_p^0).$$ There is also a remark that the contributions from the timelike and longitudinal photons cancel amongst themselves leaving us just with the contribution from the transverse photons.

I understand from the remark that only the radiation energy is considered. What about the energy of the non-radiating field in the vacuum (that is: out of the charges) calculated above?

Comment: Of course, the _free_ electromagnetic field does not contain contributions from static charges. It contains only radiation because that's (by definition) what you can have in the absence of charge.

Comment: Well, that makes sense. Perhaps it should be clearly stated in texts about quantization of electromagnetic field. Otherwise the reader naturally takes all EM field.